# Ansible inventory: how to identify hosts by port

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, nat, ansible-inventory

I have set 2 servers for testing purposes, which are behind a NAT network. So I configured port forwarding to SSH port for both of them.

My inventory file looks like this:

```
[webservers]
example.com:12021
example.com:12121

[webservers:vars]
ansible_user=root
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/test/keys/id_ed25519
```

But Ansible only identifies one of them(whichever is first in the list). My "hack" to run ansible-playbook commands on both of them is by changing the order in the hostlist, and running the playbook twice.

So, is there any way to identify the hosts **by port number**, and not by hostname?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use any label you like:

```
[webservers]
server1 ansible_host=example.com ansible_port=12021
server2 ansible_host=example.com ansible_port=12121
```

Comment: It worked, but with minor change: ports had to be set with ansible_port parameter explicitly, not in the ansible_host part.
Accept the edit so I can set the answer as accepted (because current version of the answer is not working).
Thank you very much!:)